# 'word wrapping' on li rather than individual words

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am generating a list of tags (in an `ul`/`li` format) that I would like to have the line break occur on the `li` and not on the individual words or characters within the `li`.

The only css command that I have found to do anything so far was `word-break` where if it is `break-all` it will break after any character, `normal` (or anything else which will default to `normal`) has it breaking after a space or a dash `-`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8vcgtta)

My css is as follows currently:

```
li { 
  display: inline;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-break: normal;
}
```

Comment: You mean like this?: - https://jsfiddle.net/v8vcgtta/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just need to set `li` as `display:inline-block`

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This longword tag One</li>
  <li>This longword tag Two</li>
  <li>ThislongwordtagThree</li>
  <li>This longword tag Four</li>
  <li>This longword tag Five</li>
  <li>This longword tag Six</li>
  <li>This longword tag Seven</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>This longword tag One</li>
  <li>This longword tag Two</li>
  <li>ThislongwordtagThree</li>
  <li>This longword tag Four</li>
  <li>This longword tag Five</li>
  <li>This longword tag Six</li>
  <li>This longword tag Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I needed - thank you. I'll mark it as correct when it allows me to. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need, then simply adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to your `li` rule will do the trick:

```
li { 
  display: inline;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht54h9nf/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` or `float: left;`